# Call Rails Action to get data through Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have been trying to call my model from Javascript and the half is already done, but I want to pass the results from one method in my model to another method in my model and the receive the output in my view.

My model looks like:

```
class Calculator

    def initialize( consumption, production )
        @consumption = consumption
        @production = production
    end

    def calc_raw

        #Calculations
        #output -> hash with outputs


    end

    def calc_test
        raw = calc_raw
        # calculation with output from calc_raw
        #data -> return to AJAX.
        return data
    end

end
```

My controller looks like: `energycalcsb_controller.rb`

```
class Api::V2::EnergycalcsbController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
    def index

    end

    def create
        input1 = params[:data][0].to_i
        input2 = params[:data][1].to_i
        @calc = Calculator.new(input1,input2)
        energy_calc_results = @calc.calc_raw


        render status: 200, json: {
            message: "Succesful data calculation",
            data_output: energy_calc_results
            }.to_json


    end   


end
```

In my view:

```
<script >

// Converting entries by user to integer
    var myInteger1; 
    myInteger1 = parseInt(a); //Jahreshausverbrauch (kWh)
    var myInteger2; 
    myInteger2 = parseInt(b); //PV-Große (kWp)


$(function () {


    // Calling my API with AJAX

      $.ajax({ 
      type: 'POST', 
      url: '/api/v2/energycalcsb', 
      data: {"data":[myInteger1,myInteger2]}, 
      dataType: 'json', 
      success: function(data){ //Sending the output to a function

        console.log('success', data); //Help to print the output of the API
      } 
      }); //AJAX to energy calculation module

 });    


</script>
```

I want to receive the `data` from `calc_test` in my javascript function (AJAX-data)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do that isn't working?

Comment: In my AJAX call I want to receive the data from calc_test (I do some operations in calc_test with the output from calc_raw and then this result I send it to AJAX). That means, I have to send data from one method to another in my model. calc_raw->calc_test->AJAX->print

Comment: I understand what you're generally trying to accomplish, but is the problem that you are not receiving the data you expect back from your AJAX call, or you don't know how to work with the data once it is sent back?

Comment: Exactly, I do not how to achieve this. How to send them back?

Comment: What you are currently getting in data object? `console.log('success', data);`

Answer (score 0):

In your block:

```
success: function(data){ //Sending the output to a function
  console.log('success', data);
}
```

You can operate on the data right here. You can access your returned value with `data.data_access`, and perform any action you like upon it. Also, you shouldn't need the `.to_json` in your create action.

Comment: You are right, but the thing is that this code should be hidden. But I already found the answer. I'll post it

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in this way:

From my controller I call the method I want to use in my model.

```
energy_calc_results = @calc.calc_test
```

and in `calc_raw` add:

```
  return output
```